# Different result by converting serverdate(iso) to jsdate with momentjs in browsers. How to solve it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, momentjs, mozilla

**Chrome 74**

```
moment("1982-04-01T00:00:00").toDate()
```

Thu Apr 01 1982 01:00:00 GMT+0400 (Moscow Summer Time)

**Mozilla 67**

```
moment("1982-04-01T00:00:00").toDate()
```

Date 1982-03-31T21:00:00.000Z

Why? How correct convert serverdate to jsdate in different browsers? 
Why moment doesn't work correctly?

Comment: It does work? One date *displays* UTC time, the other time with offset but both are ultimately the same date.

Comment: How I must write correctly to execute moment syntax? 
To get one correct result in different browsers? 
01 april of 1982 year

Comment: Both are correct. They just format the Date object differently but still represent the exact same date and time.

Comment: How does moment.js turn "1982-04-01T00:00:00" into "Thu Apr 01 1982 01:00:00 GMT+040"? The time should be 00:00:00, not 01:00:00. The conversion "1982-04-01T00:00:00" to "1982-03-31T21:00:00.000Z" indicates an offset of 03:00, not 04:00.